# iTextSharp in version 4.1.6 (with previous licence conditions)

Tags: .net, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I have an old project that is using iTextSharp library for PDF generation. iTextSharp DLL is added as reference to the project. iTextSharp was originally available under the LGPL licence. Some time ago the licence has changed to be AGPL (in release 5.0.0) that is copy left so you'd have to GPL all your code if you used it.

My problem is that I don't know when I downloaded the DLL file that is linked in my project. I don't know if the DLL is still under LGPL or it is already under AGPL. And that would mean that I have to GPL my project.

Is there any way to check what is the version of iTextSharp when you have only the DLL? Or what is the licence of it?

Or is there any place where I can download old version of iTextSharp that is still under LGPL so I'll be sure I'm not breaking the licence by not making my project GPL?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

seems like iTextSharp maintainers removed iTextSharp 4.1.6 from SourceForge, anyway you can try to simply Google for "itextsharp-4.1.6.zip" to find alternative download sources

---

**EDIT:** here is the link for 4.1.6 dll: http://pdfviewernet.googlecode.com/svn-history/r55/trunk/PDFView/PDFView/lib/itextsharp.dll

Comment: -1 Of course I did try this before asking this question on SO with no success. If you can google better then I can please provide link to alternative download source that you have found.

Comment: here is the link for 4.1.6 dll: [http://pdfviewernet.googlecode.com/svn-history/r55/trunk/PDFView/PDFView/lib/itextsharp.dll](http://pdfviewernet.googlecode.com/svn-history/r55/trunk/PDFView/PDFView/lib/itextsharp.dll)

Comment: Great, thank you! If you edit your answer and put your link there I will delete my down vote (I cannot do it unless you edit your answer) and give you upvote instead. Maybe I'll also accept it.

Comment: Ok I have edited your answer to include link myself so I could accept it. However it will take some time to the edit to be accepted by somebody with enough reputation.

Comment: Can I use it for commercial purpose (4.1.6.0) ?

Answer (score 32):

iTextSharp (LGPL / MPL) 4.1.6 is available via NuGet.

For more information, see http://nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp-LGPL.

Answer (score 5):

Right click on the dll and go the Properties, under the Details tab it the version number should be listed.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like my DLL is already 5.0.1 so I should not be should it. Is there any way to download version 4.1.6 or lower ?

Comment: you can download it here -> http://itextsharp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/itextsharp/tags/iTextSharp_4_1_6/  click the "Download GNU tarball" link and build it yourself. But this version is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 4):

`iTextSharp 4.1.6` has [sources on github](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/releases/tag/iTextSharp_4_1_6).

Answer (score 2):

You can also check the PDF it generates' Document Info values, the "Producer" in particular.  In Adobe Reader you hit ctrl+D and go to the first tab.