# Type 'iTextSharp.text.Table' is not defined

Tags: vb.net

I want to know why Type 'iTextSharp.text.Table' is not defined. I already imported iTextSharp.text , iTextSharp.text.pdf, iTextSharp.text.html, iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.

Dim gvTable As New **iTextSharp.text.Table**(columns, tableRows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In searching the Internet the only thing I could find about `iTextSharp.Text.Table` was example code. I looked at the SVN on SourceForge and there is no `Table` that is part of the text namespace, it looks like it was deprecated in the current version. Your best bet would be to use [`iTextSharp.text.pdf.PDFPTable`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTable.html). (Documentation from iText link) or to find a Version of iTextSharp previous to version 5. If you look at this [SO Question/Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680391/itextsharp-in-version-4-16-with-previous-licence-conditions) there is a link to [**`iTextSharp version 4.1.6`**](http://pdfviewernet.googlecode.com/svn-history/r55/trunk/PDFView/PDFView/lib/itextsharp.dll) this version does have iTextSharp.text.Table. Here also is a [blog](http://blog.bytescout.com/2011_04_01_archive.html) that has links to the Source and dll.

Comment: If I don't use the iTextSharp, what else can I use to save my page to PDF format. (including saving gridview)

Comment: @SherleneTan Did you try the links to the older version of iTextSharp that I linked to, that version does have the Method you are looking for.  I am not sure of what the capabilities of the other librarys are so I can not really recommend one.

Comment: Thank you! I have fixed the problem. However, my gridview is using databind instead of boundfield. Is there any other way of importing the gridview into PDF?

I use the code from this website: (http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-ASP.Net-GridView-to-PDF-with-Custom-Columns-Widths-using-iTextSharp.aspx)

Comment: @SherleneTan To be honest with you I am not that familiar with Asp.Net, I develop primarily in Wpf and Winforms .