# The type or namespace name 'Table' does not exist in the namespace 'iTextSharp.text'

Tags: c#, .net, itext

Hi While working on this already written code, i am facing problem to resolve this issue. Please help me out.

In following code, itextsharp.text.table  and cell does not exists issue was found, i added itexsharp  dll to avoid it still it is not getting remove.

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
...

    iTextSharp.text.Table dataTable = new iTextSharp.text.Table(2);
    dataTable.DefaultHorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    dataTable.DefaultVerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
    dataTable.Border = 1;
    dataTable.AutoFillEmptyCells = false;
    dataTable.Padding = 1;
    dataTable.SpaceInsideCell = 1;
    dataTable.WidthPercentage = 100;
    dataTable.Convert2pdfptable = true;
    dataTable.TableFitsPage = true;
    //=============Adding 01 Row==================
    iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("images/LOGO4.GIF");
    iTextSharp.text.Image address = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("images/address3.GIF");
    Cell logo = new Cell(img);
    dataTable.AddCell(logo);
    Cell addres = new Cell(address);
    dataTable.AddCell(addres);
...
```

Not able to resolve although i read number of related post and articles.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type 'iTextSharp.text.Table' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571922/type-itextsharp-text-table-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using an old version of a deprecated library version (Table has been replaced by [PdfPTable](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText5/java/5.5.13.1/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTable.html)) (iTextSharp/iText 5 has been deprecated in favor of [iText 7](https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/itext-7-community), which has the exact same license model). In any case, you can check out documentation about tables for iTextSharp/iText 5 [here](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/books/best-itext-questions-stack-overflow/tables) and [here](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/books/itext-action-second-edition/itext-5-tables). For iText 7, you can find similar documentation [here](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/books/best-itext-7-questions-stackoverflow/tables) and [here](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-7/tables-and-fonts) (unfortunately, these are all Java examples, but the API is pretty much the same).