# C# Winforms PDF Reader

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf

i want to create PDF viewer using C# windows forms. It have to look like Adobe Acrobat Reader, but more less functinal (just zoom and rotate). I dont want to use Acrobat Reader or another progs for that.
This is a sample i found: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37458/PDF-Viewer-Control-Without-Acrobat-Reader-Installe
but they are using iTextSharp and PDFlibe.net librarys which are not free. 
Can someone point me on a good way or free library for that?

Comment: iTextSharp 4 is free (LGPL). Look in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680391/itextsharp-in-version-4-1-6-with-previous-licence-conditions

And did you mean that iTextSharp and PDFlibe.net are not free (instead of 'now')?

Comment: yes, sorry, i meant they are "not" free.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've answered your own question already! I've only used [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) in the past, so I can't comment on PDFlibe.net. It looks like the new version of iTextSharp uses a more restrictive license, so I'd look for v4 (google is your friend), which should suffice for what you need.

Comment: Yes, thank You! As i understand i still can use iTextSharp v 4.1.6 for my commercial program, withouth paying for a licens. But I know English bad, Can you pleace check if im right? there is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517776/itextsharp-license

Comment: I'd say you should follow [this advice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9048657/1397117), which says you can use it, but I'd recommend consulting with a lawyer if this is intended for a commercial product.